# MySQL export column to file as update statements

Tags: php, mysql

Im creating a php function that will do find/replace task in the DB and the I think fastest way without interrupting the database is to do the following:

1. Dump the column into into a file
2. Edit it through  `file_get_contents` , `str_replace` and  `file_put_contents` php functions.
3. Execute the query file

Is there a cleaner query to  produce this effect?

My ugly code goes like this..

```
SELECT 
CONCAT("UPDATE copy_wp_posts SET post_content = '", 
post_content ,
"' where ID = ", 
ID, ";") as 'query' from wp_posts 
where post_type IN ('page','post') 
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/update-query.mysql;
```

which produces a file that has this code..

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = 'The quick brown..'    where ID = 34135;
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor..'  where ID = 34136;
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = 'Copacobana chuchu..'  where ID = 34137;
List goes on...
```

I will just do find and replace in this file and run it, updating the table. However Im not sure if this is error proof as it is plagued with " and '' especially when it comes to `post_content` column.

Comment: `CONCAT(... , REPLACE(post_content, '\'', '\\\''), ...)`? And try to avoid dquotes for string literals in MySQL.

Comment: I think an INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY with the VALUES option would execute faster

Comment: @Strawberry That's true (one statement instead a bunch of), but 1) it may exceed max_packet_size 2) if one data cause fail the whole statement will fail.